# Concatenating Partial Path in Jade Template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a Jade template on an Express project that looks something like this (simplified for brevity):

```
!!! 5
head
    ...
body
    include path/to/partial
```

What I am trying to figure out is dynamically generate the partial's path so that I could easily swap out the partial based on a server variable.  Since `path/to/partial` isn't a string, is there a way to provide the concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that with Jade, it's static (and by design as per TJ).